# Typescript treat any as unknown

Tags: typescript

Today I ran into a runtime exception when used a 3rd party library.
It exposes a comparator prop

```
comparator: (value1: any, value2: any) => any
```

And the issue was the comparator function was

```
value1.toString().localCompare(value2.toString())
```

And value1/value2 were null and BOOM a runtime exception.

If the declaration was:

```
comparator: (value1: unknown, value2: unknown) => any
```

That would have saved me from this exception as unknown is similar to null in when trying to access its props.

Is there a way to configure tsconfig to treat any as unknown?
Or at least from 3rd party?

The least desired option is a flag to enforce type declarations on function params then, to enforce NOT using any.

Comment: Well first of all, why would it be `any` in the first place? Does this 3rd party library not give its own types? If they do, then open an issue and complain about this typing.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible.  There was an idea at one point to introduce a `--strictAny` flag that would have done this, but it was eventually declined for reasons described in [ms/TS#24737](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24737).  You'd have to work around it in some way, such as a linter rule to disallow `any` (which you don't want to do). Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you both for the response. I can open an issue about the typing that's a good idea. But till then I want something to protect me. I don't have a problem to disallow any, but the typing is coming from a third party library. Or maybe I got you wrong @jcalz? And one more option in mind, npm patch?

Comment: Right, it wouldn't give you that behavior; it would be a workaround: the linter would just complain about the library, and you'd have to use a locally-modified version of it (via some mechanism... maybe npm patch, not an expert on that so ‍♂️) or get the upstream folks to change it, or just be warned that the issue is present so you can be more careful.  So, how should I proceed here?  Do you want to see an answer to "Is there a way to configure tsconfig to treat any as unknown?" Or is the question something else?